# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^ka_{2^k}$ converges…

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in[0,\infty[^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotonically decreasing sequence, so that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^ka_{2^k}$ converges. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and test $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ for convergence.

---

Can anybody…explain to me what this exercise even asks of me? I have trouble understanding it in the first place. Is $a_n=2^ka_{2^k}$ here or something else? If so am I simply supposed to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{n}a_{2^{n}}$ converges? Seems unlikely. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=2^{k}}^{2^{k+1}-1} a_n \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k} a_{2^{k}} < \infty.
$$
So you group the elements of the original sequence into exponentially larger blocks, and use monotonicity in each block.

Answer (score 1):

This is Cauchy's condensation test, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test